# Missing row after triggered update in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I have a trigger fired update on my table but I noticed that after the update is made without errors when I'm trying to view the updated value on my datalist, this particular value is missing.

This is my Table's stracture:

```
CREATE TABLE "customer" (
    "customerid" int NOT NULL,
    "personid" int,
    "number_of_items" int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    CONSTRAINT customer_pk PRIMARY KEY ("customerid")
) WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

This is the procedure which is called within the Trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION updatecustomer() RETURNS trigger AS $purchase$
    BEGIN
        UPDATE "customer" SET "number_of_items" = "number_of_items" + 1
        WHERE "customerid" = 29614;

        RETURN NULL;

    END
$purchase$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This is my Trigger's code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updatecustomer AFTER INSERT ON "salesorderdetail"
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE updatecustomer();
```

Before and After in my data:

[image: Before The Update][image: After The Update]

Comment: Any answer or suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:
`CREATE TRIGGER updatecustomer AFTER INSERT ON "salesorderdetail"
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE updatecustomer();`